# kubernetes Back restarting container issue, Rest-api pod

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

i am a beginner, i am trying to create an hyperledger based IoT environment. only issue i am facing is that my rest-api pod gets into crashloopbackoff state, i have checked the logs, it shows the following error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRjHe.png)

Comment: well, that's an issue in your deployed application. When the container does not come up, or fails continuously, the pod moves into status Crashloopbackoff.

Comment: yargs npm package needs minimum node js v10, update your dockerfile to have the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your container image is broken. Nothing to do with k8s.

it seems your container is using a node.js version that it does not support.

try `docker run <your_image>`